# Задать класс нескольким объектам с задержкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице выводится список `<ul>`, в котором есть несколько элементов `<li>`.

Необходимо элементу внутри каждого `<li>` добавить класс так, чтобы после первого добавления класс последующим элементам добавлялся с задержкой.

Как я понял, нужно использовать методы. Код примерно такой:

```
var delay = 1;
$("ul.gallery").find('li').each(function() {
    $("div.element").find('flip-wrap').one("load", function() {
        $("img.olol").parent().delay(delay).addClass('loaded', 300);
        delay += 200;
    }).each(function() {
        $("img.olol").load();
        Waypoint.refreshAll();
    });;
});
```

Исходный код JS-плагина такой:

```
if ($this.hasClass('portfolio-shortcode')) {
    var delay = 1;
    $this.find('.element').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('img').one("load", function() {
            jQuery(this).parent().delay(delay).addClass('img-loaded', 300);
             delay += 200;
        }).each(function() {
            if (this.complete) {
                jQuery(this).load();
                Waypoint.refreshAll();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>
        <div class="element">
            <div class="element-inner">
                <div class="flip-wrap">
                    <div class="flip-img-wrap">
                        <img src="" class="olol" alt="Гостиная альт">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .one не работает. Без нее работает, но класс задается всем элементам одновременно, а нужно - по очереди

Comment: <li><div class="element"><div class="element-inner"><div class="flip-wrap"><div class="flip-img-wrap"><img src="" class="olol" alt="Гостиная альт"></div></div></div></div></div></li>

Comment: Забыл, извиняюсь. Он таки есть. Не пойму, может реально "load" не нужен. Но и без него не работает.

Comment: Пока что могу сказать, что `$("div.element")` берёт **все** div'ы с классом `element`, а не только внутри одного `<li>`, равно как и `$("img.olol")`. Думаю, это сходу ломает всю логику внутри обоих `.each()`.

Comment: `one("load"` в коде этого несколько странного плагина используется, так как событие `load` потом генерируется с помощью `jQuery(this).load()`. Вам же для простой задержки перед добавлением класса это ни к чему.

Comment: Может попробовать как-то через $this раз $("div.element") все портит, только получается же $this нужно приравнять к чем-нибудь, чтобы использовать в функции?

Comment: Каким элементам надо всё же класс добавить? Элементам `<div class="flip-img-wrap">`? И нужно создать очередь из всех этих элементов, или отдельные очереди для каждого `<li>`?

Comment: По идее это работать должно так: найти ul{ в каждом li найти img один раз{ добавить родителю img класс с задержкой, прибавить задержку}}

Comment: Элементам <div class="flip-img-wrap"> добавить класс

Comment: в каждом li  только одна картинка. Значит очередь из li

Comment: Шикардятина какая!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для задания задержки можно использовать `setTimeout` и функцию. Такой подход также даёт возможность останавливать или изменять время на каждой итерации.

Краткий пример (урезанный HTML-код, сохраняющий идею и подходящий под JS-код):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $elements = $(".gallery .flip-img-wrap");
    var delay = 1000;

    (function add(i) {
        $elements.eq(i).addClass("loaded");
        if (i < $elements.length - 1) {
            setTimeout(function() { add(i + 1); }, delay);
        }
    })(0);
});
```

```css
.flip-img-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.loaded {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gallery">
    <li class="flip-img-wrap"></li>
    <li class="flip-img-wrap"></li>
    <li class="flip-img-wrap"></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Полный пример (с сохранением исходной HTML-структуры): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex2fe9ch/).

Comment: УРА! Спасибо огромное! Адски шикарно!

Comment: @Александр на здоровье. Не знаю, могут ли незарегистрированные пользователи отмечать ответы как правильные...

Comment: Ради такого и зарегиться не лень=)

Answer (score 1):

Если задача - показывать анимацию загрузки с некоторой задержкой, то можно обойтись без setTimeout, использовав css `transition-delay`:

```
.loaded {
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
```