# Добавлять класс в цикле с задержкой

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать добавление класса к блоку в цикле.  К примеру у меня есть  несколько блоков и хочу чтоб каждому по очереди добавлялся  класс "current"  то-есть каждый блок был какое-то время активен и так бесконечно.

```
<div id="class-loop">
    <div>
        test1
    </div>
    <div>
        test2
    </div>
    <div>
        test3
    </div>
    <div>
        test4
    </div>
</div>
```

Я пробовал делать циклом, но он у меня проходит один раз по элементам и останавливается.
Пробовал без    цикла на jquery но тут у меня что-то странное выходит. Подскажите как сделать правильно буду благодарен

```js
setInterval(function() {
    $('#class-loop > div:nth-child(1)')
        .addClass('current')
        .next()
        .removeClass('current')
        .end()
        .appendTo('#class-loop');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.current{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="class-loop">
    <div>
        test1
    </div>
    <div>
        test2
    </div>
    <div>
        test3
    </div>
    <div>
        test4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Взгляните тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448672/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var $classLoop = $('#class-loop > div'),
  i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  $classLoop.removeClass('current').filter($classLoop[i]).toggleClass('current');
  i < $classLoop.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;
}, 3000);
```

```css
.current {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="class-loop">
  <div>test1</div>
  <div>test2</div>
  <div>test3</div>
  <div>test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Устанавливаем класс для первого элемента
  $('#class-loop > div:nth-child(1)').addClass('current');
  
  setInterval(function() {
    // Находим текущий элемент и убираем у него класс
    var cur = $('#class-loop > .current').removeClass('current');
    // Берем следующий элемент
    var next = cur.next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
      // Если следующего не оказалось, то берем первый
      next = cur.parent().children(':first');
    }
    // Устанавливаем найденному элементу нужный класс
    next.addClass('current');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="class-loop">
  <div>
    test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2
  </div>
  <div>
    test3
  </div>
  <div>
    test4
  </div>
</div>
```